# Why is Cv greater than Cp during anomolous expansion of water?

Tags: thermodynamics

Well, in general $c_p> c_v$ for most cases but for water having anomolous expansion from $0^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ to $4^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ the order is just opposite, $c_v >c_p$, why?

Comment: The wikipedia article on heat capacity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity), or your thermodynamics textbook, will give the equation for the the difference of Cp and Cv in terms of partial derivatives of P and V vs T.  It is readily seen that the anomalous expansion (i.e. dV/dT < 0) is directly responsible for the difference.